# 32 bit vs 64 bit systems - is the memory limit in bits or bytes?

Tags: x86, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit, cpu-architecture, 32-bit

I was reading up on the difference between 32-bit and 64-bit systems, and came across this blog in the process: https://www.zdnet.com/article/clearing-up-the-3264-bit-memory-limit-confusion/

Now I'm confused because in this blog they provide a note as follows:

> Note: Wondering how we arrive at that 4GB limit? Here's the math for 32-bit systems:
>
> 2^32 = 4,294,967,296 bytes 4,294,967,296 / (1,024 x 1,024) = 4,096 MB = 4GB
>
> It's different for 64-bit:
>
> 2^64 = 18,446,744,073,709,551,616 18,446,744,073,709,551,616 / (1,024 x 1,024) = 16EB (exabytes)

They state that whether a program is 32 bit or 64 bit changes the memory limit it can use.

What I don't understand is, how the bits change into bytes?  If you work out 2 bits to the power of 32, surely the result is 4,294,967,296 *bits* and not *bytes*?  And if this were so, then the memory limit on a 32-bit system would be 4 Giga*Bits* and not 4 Giga*Bytes*?

Can someone explain how this works out?  Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: looking for a duplicate now; I think I saw one earlier today.  Yup, found it in my browser history :)

Comment: can you provide a link to the duplicate?  I did search through several questions on the site and couldn't find anything similar.

Comment: It's at the top of the page, because I closed the question as a duplicate.  The answer I posted is also a complete answer, so I decided not to make it just a comment even though I was planning to close it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

each separately-addressable memory location is a byte.  Memory is not bit-addressable, only in byte chunks or larger.  That's why setting a single bit in a bitmap requires a read-modify-write of the containing byte or word.